# Replacing files in source/repo folder (local) connected to Azure Devops (web) using GIT via drag and drop method

Tags: git, azure-devops, asp.net-core-3.1

I am working on upgrading from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.1.  I am using Azure Devops with GIT for Source Control.  Due to the significant changes, I made a copy of my solution and worked through the upgrade "opportunities".  Before I step blindly into this, has anyone trashed the current solution and pasted an upgraded version into a folder connected via Azure Devops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bit the bullet and went forward with the copy paste.  In Folder A, I had my original solution with all the projects, .gitignore, .gitattributes and .git folder that associated it with the source control.

In Folder B, I had a copy of all of my projects. I used this to work through the update from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to ASP.NET Core 3.1.1.

I removed all files in Folder A except for the .gitignore, .gitattributes files and the .git folder.  I then copied my solution from Folder B into Folder A.  I deleted the .vs and bin and obj folders in the web project.

When I loaded the app in VS 2019, the source control indicated all of the pending changes and I was able to carry on as normal. There is probably a more appropriate approach, but to me, this update was substantial enough to work through it in a copied environment.

Answer (score 0):

> has anyone trashed the current solution and pasted an upgraded version into a folder connected via Azure Devops?

Since you are using the Azure Devops with GIT for Source Control, you could add yourself as the Reviewers: **Branches**->**Branch policies**->**Automatically include code reviewers**:

[image]

[image]

In this case, you could to know any change for the current solution.

If I do not understand your question correct, you could update your question more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: First @Leo thank you fro the reply.  What I am trying to do is replace all of the repo folder with all of the copy folder content.  I am looking for any one that possibly has done this so I know what to expect. For example, Folder A is my original folder with the git files connect to Azure Devops source control and CI.  I create Folder B and added a copy of my solution so that I could work through the upgrade.  Folder B is not connected to source control.  I want to copy the solutions files from folder B to folder A and am looking for any gotchas I may not have considered.